# turn all files in a folder into function aliases with bash

Tags: python, bash, alias

I have a folder of python files. I want to turn them into functions I can call in bash. This following one-liner is in my profile text file loading at bash login, but it doesn't work. How can I fix it?

```
for i in `ls ~/Dropbox/Documents/tools/python`; do 
  fullfilename=$(basename "$i");
  filename="${fullfilename%.*}";
  $("alias $filename='/usr/local/bin/python3.3 ~/Dropbox/Documents/tools/python/$fullfilename '");
done
```

EDIT:
per Liviu Chircu's recommendation, I removed the " before and after the alias command. Following is now the new code:

```
for i in `ls ~/Dropbox/Documents/tools/python`; do 
  fullfilename=$(basename "$i");
  filename="${fullfilename%.*}";
  $(alias $filename='/usr/local/bin/python3.3 ~/Dropbox/Documents/tools/python/$fullfilename ');
done
```

Now I get this error:

```
$ findfactors 40
-bash: findfactors: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three steps to make the Python scripts executable from `bash`.

First, at the top of every file in that directory, add the following line to tell `bash` which interpreter to use.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.3
```

Second, set all those files to executable.

```
chmod u+x ~/Dropbox/Documents/tools/python/*
```

Third, add that directory to your `PATH`. This one goes in `~/.bashrc`, while the other two are one-time things.

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Dropbox/Documents/tools/python
```

Comment: I would vote up, but I don't have enough reputation; excellent unix-style solution compared to my ugly attempt at this!

Comment: @Mica, No worries. Enjoy your new Python script convenience! :)

Comment: Sometimes `#!/usr/bin/env python3.3` is preferred to `#!/usr/local/bin/python3.3`. The former will use the `PATH` to search for `python3.3`, while the latter uses a hard coded location.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to remove *"* from your alias command.

Try

```
$(alias $filename='/usr/local/bin/python3.3 ~/Dropbox/Documents/tools/python/$fullfilename ');
```

Instead of

```
$("alias $filename='/usr/local/bin/python3.3 ~/Dropbox/Documents/tools/python/$fullfilename '");
```

Comment: Consider moving this code over to ~/.bashrc. Also follow merlin's 1) and 2) tips.

Comment: any reason I should be using ~/.bashrc over /etc/profile? also, I have textmate; turning a python file into an executable is as easy as going to the beginning of the file, typing py, hitting tab, and saving :D

Comment: /etc/profile is a system-wide config file - usually should be left intact. Also, you'd have to take care of the PATH. Anyway, you gave me a nice idea for my .vimrc - thanks :)

Comment: I don't know where this code came from, and I don't understand it, but this is in my /etc/profile:`if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
 eval \`/usr/libexec/path_helper -s\`
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
 [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi`; is that what you mean by "take care of the PATH"?

Comment: You started two discussion threads in one comment. My "Also" marks the start of an answer to your textmate-path-to-binaries topic :) sorry if I confused you

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like

```sh
for i in "$HOME"/Dropbox/Documents/tools/python/*; do 
  fullfilename="$(basename "$i")"
  filename="${fullfilename%.*}"      
  alias "$filename"="/usr/local/bin/python3.3 ~/Dropbox/Documents/tools/python/$fullfilename" 
done
```

Comment: -bash: alias: =/usr/local/bin/python3.3 ~/Dropbox/Documents/tools/python/"$fullfilename": not found
-bash: alias: =/usr/local/bin/python3.3 ~/Dropbox/Documents/tools/python/"$fullfilename": not found

Comment: @Mica Try it again, swapped a variable